# How to delete bulk documents in mongodb via spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to delete bulk records in mongodb. 
I tried various ways. One of multiple approach, shown code below.

```
final Query query = new Query(criteria);
BulkWriteResult execute = template.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, Books.class).remove(query).execute();
```

Query matches 1101872 documents in books collection. Even though I do bulk remove, It took more than half an hour and not yet deleted.

Did I make any mistake on the approach or Do I need to follow some other way?

Comment: do you have index on the collection matching your criteria

Comment: no. If I would have indexes, is the above process right?

Comment: Ya. there is nothing wrong with the process I believe, the reason it is taking so much time is, you have a criteria on which you wan to delete documents. To achieve this, mongo has to search the documents matching this criteria, which will take time, depending on the query you have